# How can I refactor this hideous beast?

Tags: php, arrays, object, refactoring

I have a query that I execute, then I use

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $data[] = $row;
```

I know this is grotesque, but I'm unsure how to make this an object or a multidimensional array so I just made something like this..

```
$NUH2016 = array();
$NUH2017 = array();
$NUH2018 = array();
$NUH2019 = array();
$NUH2020 = array();
$NUH2021 = array();
$RBN2016 = array();
$RBN2017 = array(); ...

...$GDT2019 = array();
$GDT2020 = array();
$GDT2021 = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $data[] = $row;
        if($row['Location'] == 'NUH' && $row['Year'] == '2016'){
            $NUH2016[] = $row['P_1'];
            $NUH2016[] = $row['P_2'];
            $NUH2016[] = $row['P_3'];
            $NUH2016[] = $row['P_4'];
        }
        if($row['Location'] == 'NUH' && $row['Year'] == '2017'){
            $NUH2017[] = $row['P_1'];
            $NUH2017[] = $row['P_2'];
            $NUH2017[] = $row['P_3'];
            $NUH2017[] = $row['P_4'];
        }
        //...for all locations and years

 ...then
 $content = array();
$results = array();

$NUH2016_total = array_sum($NUH2016);
$NUH2017_total = array_sum($NUH2017);
$NUH2018_total = array_sum($NUH2018);
$NUH2019_total = array_sum($NUH2019);
$NUH2020_total = array_sum($NUH2020);
$NUH2021_total = array_sum($NUH2021);


$results['NUH~2016'] = $NUH2016_total;
$results['NUH~2017'] = $NUH2017_total;
$results['NUH~2018'] = $NUH2018_total;
$results['NUH~2019'] = $NUH2019_total;
$results['NUH~2020'] = $NUH2020_total;
$results['NUH~2021'] = $NUH2021_total;

$RBN2016_total = array_sum($RBN2016);
$RBN2017_total = array_sum($RBN2017);
$RBN2018_total = array_sum($RBN2018);
$RBN2019_total = array_sum($RBN2019);
$RBN2020_total = array_sum($RBN2020);
$RBN2021_total = array_sum($RBN2021);


$results['RBN~2016'] = $RBN2016_total;
$results['RBN~2017'] = $RBN2017_total;
$results['RBN~2018'] = $RBN2018_total;
$results['RBN~2019'] = $RBN2019_total;
$results['RBN~2020'] = $RBN2020_total;
$results['RBN~2021'] = $RBN2021_total;
...etc

$content['Results'] = $results;
$response = json_encode($content);
echo $response;
```

So what I want to do is make an object or associative array that looks like this.

```
content {
        produced hours{   
                       nuh{ 2016:16,000
                            2017:8,000
                            ...
                           }
                       rbn{ 2016:9,000
                            2017:whatever
                            ....
                      }
           man hours{
                       nuh{ 2016:4,000
                            2017:2,000
                            ...
                           }
                       rbn{ 2016:1,000
                            2017:more stuff
                            ....
                      }
```

but I'm pretty new to php objects. How can I refactor it so that I don't have to initialize every single empty array, have a bunch of if statements to make each entry from the query fit into an array to be summed, and then put it all into an object at the end to get back from an ajax success function?

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe questions about refactoring are better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (you are more likely to get good answers there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to declare so many arrays. Simply change your `while()` loop in the following way,

```
$resultArr = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $tmpArr = array($row['P_1'], $row['P_2'], $row['P_3'], $row['P_4']);
    $sumTotal = array_sum($tmpArr);
    $tmpArr['sumTotal'] = $sumTotal; 
    $resultArr[$row['Location']][$row['Year']][] = $tmpArr;
}
```

Later, apply `json_encode()` on the result array like this,

```
$json = json_encode($resultArr);
```

---

**Sidenote**: If you want to see the complete array structure, do `var_dump($resultArr);`

Comment: This would also work very well! Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can have an array of arrays, so you don't need to manually assign them all.

```
$LocationAndYears;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $LocationAndYears[$row['Location']] [$row['Year']] [0] = $row['P_1'];
    $LocationAndYears[$row['Location']] [$row['Year']] [1] = $row['P_2'];
    $LocationAndYears[$row['Location']] [$row['Year']] [2] = $row['P_3'];
    $LocationAndYears[$row['Location']] [$row['Year']] [3] = $row['P_4'];
    $LocationAndYears[$row['Location']] [$row['Year']] ['sum'] = array_sum($LocationAndYears[$row['Location']] [$row['Year']]);
}
echo $LocationAndYears['NUH']['2012'][0];
echo "Sum for 2012 at NUH:" . $LocationAndYears['NUH']['2012']['sum'];
print_r($LocationAndYears);
```

Comment: Awesome, this is totally what I was looking for. So then once you have the `$LocationAndYears['NUH']['2016'][0]` with indices 0-3, would I just use `array_sum()` on `$LocationAndYears['NUH']['2016']` to get the total? And do I do that for each year and for every location?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Yeah sorry I couldn't figure out what to do and I needed to present a proof of concept and I knew that what I did above would work.. but the word "work" is used very loosely.

Answer (score 0):

Without writing the whole thing, look into multi-dimensional arrays.
Something like this maybe...
But really I think the answer to this is to point you at multi-dimensional arrays as it's very vague

```
$data = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $location   = $row['Location'];
    $year       = $row['Year'];

    $data[$location] = $data[$location] ? $data[$location] : array();
    $data[$location][$year] = $data[$location][$year] ? $data[$location][$year] : array();

    $data[$location][$year][] = $row['P_1'];
    $data[$location][$year][] = $row['P_2'];
    $data[$location][$year][] = $row['P_3'];
    $data[$location][$year][] = $row['P_4'];
}
```